# Solving exponential simultaneous equations with 4 unknown coefficients.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

While solving for a best-fit function with the general form of an exponential equation, that is, $$y=ab^{x-c}+d,$$ I reached these following simultaneous equations as below:
\begin{align}
ab^{9-c}+d &= 100\\
ab^{14-c}+d &= 150\\
ab^{23-c}+d &= 350\\
ab^{35-c}+d &= 910\\
\end{align}

[Original picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqF7D.jpg)

Which mathematical method can we use to solve for $a, b, c$ and $d$?

Comment: Please use 
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
to format math on this site.

Comment: Please edit your question text to show what you've tried, and especially anything you had any particular difficulty with. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have $4$  independent parameters, because $a$ and $c$ only occur in the combination $a b^{-c}$.  So you shouldn't expect to solve $4$ equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no exact solution to these four equations. Here's why: First, subtract equations (2), (3), (4) by equation (1):

$$ab^{14-c}-ab^{9-c}=50$$
$$ab^{23-c}-ab^{9-c}=250$$
$$ab^{35-c}-ab^{9-c}=810$$

Now, factor out $ab^{9-c}$ from each equation:

$$ab^{9-c}(b^5-1)=50 \ \ (5)$$
$$ab^{9-c}(b^{14}-1)=250 \ \ (6)$$
$$ab^{9-c}(b^{26}-1)=810 \ \ (7)$$

Divide equation (6) by equation (5):

$$\frac{b^{14}-1}{b^5-1}=5\rightarrow b\approx 1.11636$$

Divide equation (7) by equation (5):

$$\frac{b^{26}-1}{b^5-1}=16.2 \rightarrow b\approx 1.0928$$

As you can see, there are two contradictory values of $b$, which is a problem. The best way to deal with this is to just approximate a value of $b$ which is close to both of these values, like saying $b=1.1$. Now, let's plug that back into the original equations.

However, I am going to change the equations a little. Instead of writing $ab^{9-c}$, I will write $mb^9$, where $m=ab^{-c}$. This will help make the equations easier to read, in my opinion:

$$m1.1^9+d=100$$
$$m1.1^{14}+d=150$$
$$m1.1^{23}+d=350$$
$$m1.1^{35}+d=810$$

Now, we have two equations and four unknowns, so there is no direct way to solve for $m$ and $d$. However, we can solve for $m$ and $d$ by using linear regression, where our points are $\{(1.1^9, 100), (1.1^{14}, 150), (1.1^{23}, 350), (1.1^{35}, 810)\}$. From this approach, we get $m \approx 27.1$ and $d \approx 59.6$.

To recap, here's all of the values we have solved for so far:

$$b\approx 1.1$$
$$d\approx 59.6$$
$$m=\frac{a}{b^c}=\frac{a}{1.1^c}\approx 27.1$$

Now, we have definitive, but approximate, values for $b$ and $d$. However, unfortunately, we can not solve the last equation, $\frac{a}{1.1^c}=27.1$ for $a$ and $c$ because there is only one equation and two unknowns. What you do beyond this point is up to you, but I would suggest just making $c=0$ and then solving for $a$ by substituting $c=0$ back into the equation $\frac{a}{1.1^c}=27.1$. I think that is the easiest way to come up for values of $a$ and $c$.

Finally, remember that we did a lot of rounding in this problem, so when you plug $a,b,c,d$ back into the original equations, you will get a lot of rounding error. Again, whether or not this level of rounding error is acceptable in your model is up to you. Good luck!

Comment: It is nice that you managed to get a value for $b$. You have reached the conclusion that $b$ has 2 unequal values. At this point I guess we could say that the system is inconsistent. I am surprised you decided to continue to approximate $b$!

Answer (score 1):

Writing
$$ab^{23-c}=50-d$$ and $$ab^{14-c}=910-d$$
dividing each other we get
$$b^9=\frac{350-d}{910-d}$$ doing the same with the fourth and the third equation we get
$$b^{12}=\frac{910-d}{350-d}$$
eliminating $d$
we get
$$b^{12}=\frac{1}{b^9}$$ now you can compute $b$ and so on.
Eliminating $d$ as follows:
Multiplying by $$350-d$$ we obtain
$$350b^{12}-b^{12}d-910=-d$$
so
$$350b^{12}-910=db^{12}-d$$

collecting like terms

$$350b^{12}-910=d(b^{12}-1)$$

so9 $$d=\frac{350b^{12}-910}{b^{12}-1}$$